# Convert string to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
msg1 = '"     feature1  feature2       UIN  Comop  YYYYMM  Sales  Month          grain\\n0         212       212  F1230901  220ES  201202    212      2  F1230901220ES\\n"'
def result_trans(res_str):
    print res_str 
    res_str = StringIO(res_str)


    part_hist_df = pd.read_csv(res_str, sep="\s+")
    return part_hist_df


print result_trans(msg1)
```

I need this string to be converted to pandas dataframe as below. Please can any help.

```
feature1  feature2       UIN     Comop  YYYYMM  Sales  Month          grain
212       212          F1230901  220ES  201202    212      2  F1230901220ES
```

Comment: Do you really have your data between `"` ? i.e. `' "...." '` or just `' ... '`

Comment: Data is between '...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use `pd.read_table`

```
msg1 = '"     feature1  feature2       UIN  Comop  YYYYMM  Sales  Month          grain\n0         212       212  F1230901  220ES  201202    212      2  F1230901220ES\\n"'

pd.read_table(sio(msg1.strip('""').replace('\\n','\n')), delim_whitespace=True)
```

If data is just the string, no need to `strip`

```
pd.read_table(io.StringIO(msg1), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: It does not work for me.We need to convert str to unicode then it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: @RafeelC, This fails when any value have space in between. Eg if grain has value  'abs ES'

Comment: @VikrantHole yes, because there is ambiguity there. If your delimiters are whitespace, how can pandas differentiate which ones are seps and which are not?

Comment: @RafeelC, Please can you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565221/convert-pandas-to-string-with-specific-seperator