# Convert Pandas to String with specific seperator

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':['A A','B B'],'b':[3,4]})
res = data.to_string(col_space=1)
print res
```

I have to convert pandas dataframe to string but it should have seperator like ',' and not space. Please can any one help.

Output should be like

**u'a,b\n,A A,B B\n3,4'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good old loop may be?

```
s = ','.join(data.columns) + '\n,'
for i in range(len(data.columns)):
    if i != len(data.columns) - 1:
        s = s + ','.join((data[data.columns[i]].values).astype(str)) + '\n'
    else:
        s = s + ','.join((data[data.columns[i]].values).astype(str))
```

You get

```
'a,b\n,A A,B B\n3,4'
```

Comment: Can there be any other optimised way, or say direct pandas functionality available

Comment: Doesn’t look like. Pandas to_string works row-wise where as your desired output is column-wise plus there is no way to specify a separater (comma in your case) in to_string